# Android custom Toolbar text button

Tags: android, text, icons, toolbar

I'm new and I have created a toolbar for my activity.

Is it possible to set a 'text button' instead of a res Image

I would like to have a clickable thing with 'new track' on it
instead of a plus

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/add"
    android:visible="true"
    android:title="@string/addsome"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_plus"
    app:showAsAction="always">
</item>
```

Help would be great

Comment: try to remove android:icon in <item> tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove this line android:icon="@drawable/ic_plus".

Comment: So easy?! - great ... it works - thank you @Masum + Mohit Suthar

Answer (score 3):

Remove **android:icon** inside **item** tag, you can use this type of code

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/add"
    android:visible="true"
    android:title="@string/addsome"
    app:showAsAction="always">
</item>
```